# How to perform K-fold cross validation of a convolutional neural network in matlab using an imageDataStore object

Tags: image, matlab, conv-neural-network, cross-validation

I have written a convolutional neural network in matlab using the neural network toolbox and have been able to measure its accuracy by using the example given in matlab documentation but i would now like to measure K-fold cross validation.

My code loads the data into a imageDatastore object

```
digitData = imageDatastore(digitDatasetPath ,...
        'IncludeSubfolders',true,'LabelSource','foldernames');
```

and then splits the data into train and test data

```
trainingNumFiles = 10

rng(1) % For reproducibility
[trainDigitData,testDigitData] = splitEachLabel(digitData,...
                trainingNumFiles,'randomize')
```

i then define the layers of my cnn network

I then train my network

```
convnet = trainNetwork(trainDigitData,layers,options)
```

matlab does provide some example of how t prefer cross validation but none of the example use an imageDataStore object and was wondering how i would implement it using image data store ?  should i use butyl in cvpartition? or vals = crossval(fun,X)??

thanks in advance for the help. Sorry I'm new to matlab and neural nets

Comment: I just wrote an answer for a similar question here, let me know if it doesn't work.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156963/how-to-split-an-image-datastore-for-cross-validation-in-matlab/49549278#49549278